# LAN Connection is not working properly

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet

I have Ubuntu 16 installed which was upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 with a LAN connection.

The internet stopped working after some time. It didn't restart without restarting the whole machine. After restarting the machine, it does work properly. This is my daily routine in a day 2 or 3 times.